# Diamond sub-problem: non-multiple inheritance in side branch still require class constructor

Tags: c++, inheritance, multiple-inheritance, diamond-problem

Strange problem occurred when I tried to "solve" usual diamond problem in a usual way - using virtual inheritance:

```
  A
 / \* both virtual
B   C
 \ /
  D
```

However my base class A doesn't have default constructor, so I was to call it manually from D. However when I try to add a class E into this diamond as C-inherited

```
  A
 / \* both virtual
B   C
 \ / \
  D   E
```

it is still needed to call constructor of A in E constructor manually, i.e. C doesn't what to create A from E even though there is neither multiple inheritance nor diamond A-C-E.

```
class A                     
   {public: 
      A (int _N): N(_N) {};
      void show()
        {cout<<"A"<<N;} 
    protected:
      int N;
   }; 
class B: public virtual A   
   { public: 
       B(int n): A(2*n) {};
       void show()
        { cout<<"B"<<N;} 
   }; 
class C: public virtual A   
   { public: 
       C(int n): A(3*n) {};
       void show()
        { cout<<"C"<<N;} 
   }; 
class D: public B,C 
   { public: 
       D(): B(1), C(2), A(3) {};
       void show()
        { cout<<"D"<<N;} 
   }; 

class E: public virtual C
   { public:
       E(): C(1) {};
       void show()
        { cout<<"E"<<N;} 
   }; 

int main()
  {D d;       // OK
   A *a = &d; 
   a->show(); 

   E e;        // NOT OK, no function A::A() to call in E::E()
   A *a2 = &e;
   a2->show();
   return 0;
  }
```

Is it possible to solve this issue without calling constructor of A from E? I need C to do it properly :-).

Or is it possible not to try to solve diamond problem at all:

```
A   A
|   |  no virtual at all
B   C
 \ / \
  D   E
```

and still try to declare object of class D with two instances of A but telling compiler to use A of C when colling from D each time? When I try to add

```
using C::A
```

into the declaration of D it still produce error of unambiguous base A.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it possible to solve this issue without calling constructor of A from E? I need C to do it properly :-).

The constructor for the most derived class (in this case, `E`) is responsible for calling the constructor for any virtual base classes.

The constructor of `C` cannot call the constructor of `A` because `C` is not the most derived class.  Virtual base classes are initialized *before* any direct base classes, so `E` must initialize by `A` before it can initialize `C`.

Comment: Thanks, this is understandable, so is this exact meaning of virtual inheritance? Now I see. 

Probably I don't need virtual inheritance here, unfortunately it won't be comfortable (since there are a lot of derivatives from E and each should call A constructor in the same way as C and so on). Maybe there is a way to bypass diamond problem without virtual inheritance (in a using-like way)?

Comment: @Nick:  It's kind of hard to say with an abstract example like this.  To be honest, I generally avoid complex inheritance hierarchies in code that I write.  Someone else might have a good, pragmatic solution for the general case.

Comment: I was thinking... well, I do not need C to be child of A that much in my particular case. E could be direct child of A (together with C) instead.

@James, thanks a lot again.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, virtual base class constructor calls are unlike virtual function overriding:

- you can override a virtual function in a derived class;
- you **must** override a virtual function only if the function is overridden in one of the base classes but not in others;
- you cannot not override the init-list for virtual base classes of the base class constructor.

This implies that:

- as far as virtual function overriding is concerned, virtual inheritance does not affect single inheritance at all;
- but when it comes to base class constructor calls, virtual inheritance affects every derived class.